# How many normal groups does $ℤ_{18}×ℤ_{20}$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Im trying to solve this exercise, but I can't do it. 
How many normal groups does $ℤ_{18}×ℤ_{20}$ have?

I know that $ℤ_{18}×ℤ_{20}$ is not cyclic, and a normal subgroup is a group which is invariant under conjugation, such that N is a normal subgroup iff for each $n\in N$ and each $g \in G$, $ gng^{-1} \in N$, but I dont know how apply it. How this data can help me? Thanks for reading!

Comment: It is abelian, so every subgroup is normal. =)

Comment: Yes, normal subgroups sorry, @bof

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can reduce the problem to counting the number of subgroups of each of the Sylow subgroups. Use the Chinese Remainder theorem to express the group as a product of cyclic groups of prime-power order.

Comment: Note that the [Fundamental Thm. of Finite Abelian Groups](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups) establishes the *existence* of such an expression (as an internal direct product of cyclic groups of prime-power order).

Comment: Well I express the grupo as a product subgroup of clyclic groups of $p^k$ order then ....$ℤ_{18}×ℤ_{20} \cong $ℤ_{2*3^2}×ℤ_{5 *2^2} \cong $ℤ_{2^3}×ℤ_{3^2}×ℤ_{5}$ in this step, Am I ok?

Comment: Not quite. Recall that the Chinese Remainder theorem tells you that $Z_{mn} \cong Z_m \times Z_n$ if $\operatorname{gcd)(m,n)=1$. Try applying this to $Z_{18}$ and $Z_{20}$.

Comment: Ok for $\mathbb{Z}_{18} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ and for $\mathbb{Z}_{20} \cong \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$... then how apply Sylow theorem?? Thanks @Brent

Comment: In general, a finite abelian group $G$ can be written as a direct product of its Sylow subgroups $G\cong \operatorname{Syl}_{p_1}(G) \times \dots \times \operatorname{Syl}_{p_r}(G)$. Given subgroups $P_1 \leq \operatorname{Syl}_{p_1}(G), \dots, P_r \leq \operatorname{Syl}_{p_r}(G)$, the product $P_1P_2\cdots P_r$ is a subgroup of $G$ (since $P_1,\dots,P_r$ are normal). You can show that this correspondence $(P_1,\dots,P_r) \mapsto P_1\cdots P_r$ is bijective onto the set of all subgroups of $G$. In this way, finding the subgroups of $G$ is reduced to finding subgroups of $P_1,\dots,P_r$.

Comment: I lost again, I dont have any idea how to apply...